# Scrip | Agendador de Tarefas (Nunca finaliza)

Tags: windows, cmd, task, scheduler

Olá
Criei o .BAT que deleta arquivos do dia anterior e na sequencia abre o WinSCP e executa um Script

```
@echo off
C:
cd C:\Unigrupo\
forfiles -p "C:\Unigrupo\ARQUIVOS_GERADOS" -d -1 -m *.csv -c "cmd /c del /f /q @path"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" /script=C:\Unigrupo\AcessoWinScpUnigrupo.txt
pause
exit
```

E o Script que ele chama abre um IP especifico, com user e senha e joga os arquivos .CSV dentro do diretorio HOME desse SFTP:

```
open sftp://root:1@192.0.3.29
cd /home
lcd C:\Unigrupo\ARQUIVOS_GERADOS
put "*.*"
close
cd..
cd..
cd..
exit
```

Meu problema é que quando coloco o BAT para rodar dentro do Agendador de Tarefas do Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard ele só fica executando e NUNCA termina. (Nem copia os arquivos dentro do WinSCP) Se eu rodar ele na mão, ele copia certinho.

Li que pode ser algo nos códigos, mas não faço ideia do que seja.

Podem em ajudar?

Comment: Qual usuário você configurou para executar o bat pode ser isso.

Comment: Ricardo, configurei para rodar com o "NomeDoServidor\Administrador"
Coloquei, "Executar com o usuario logado ou não"